# How to read apex classes from outside java application?

Tags: apex, api, java

Need assistance with how can I read apex class lines? which API should I use for accomplishing this REST or SOAP? Please help.

Comment: You can use SOAP, REST, Tooling, Metadata SOAP, Metadata REST, SFDX CLI, etc. It really depends on what technology options you have available to you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I checked with salesforce rest API I did not get any endpoint that I can use to read apex class code. so basically what I need to know is how to read apex class code from an outside system if I choose rest API?

Comment: `/services/data/sobjects/ApexClass/01p5000000xxxxxAAA` or `/services/data/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/MyClassName`. It gives you a response including the Body of the code.

Comment: @sfdcfox In my case, I will not have the class name of any Id to pass and get info. I will have only credentials of salesforce org. The purpose of implementation is to check vulnerabilities in code.

Comment: You can use a query: `/services/data/v50.0/query?q=SELECT+Name,Body+From+ApexClass`, listMetadata from the Metadata API, etc.

Comment: @sfdx body(code lines) is hidden in this request.

Comment: You can't scan classes in Managed Packages, but you should be able to see the source code for subscriber code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120742/discussion-between-sakshi-sehdev-and-sfdcfox).

Answer (score 0):

Hitting endpoint ->  `/services/data/v50.0/query?q=SELECT+Name,Body+From+ApexClass`

will give the list of classes and we can check the content of the apex class using its **body** attribute.

As [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) specified in the above conversation **body of classes from managed packaged will be hidden**.